# cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to log the **file's path** after being uploaded to the server but returns the following error:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

I managed to upload the files but unable to get the file path.

```
    router.post('/uploadFile',function(req,res,next){
        if(req.method == "POST"){
            var accessToken = req.query["access_token"];
            var customerID = req.decoded.userID;
            var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
                destination: function(req, file, callback) {
                    callback(null, "./public/images");
                },
                filename: function(req, file, callback) {
                    callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
                    console.log(req.file.path);
                }
            });

   var upload = multer({
                storage: Storage
            }).array("imgUploader", 3);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) correctly.

1. The initialization of multer needs to happen outside of your middleware code
2. Multer's own middleware (which you get after init) needs to execute before yours (so that it can parse request before you access).
3. If you're using array, there are multiple files being uploaded with same param name, so `req.files` should be used, not `req.file`. Combining these, your code becomes:

   ```
   var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
                   destination: function(req, file, callback) {
                       callback(null, "./public/images");
                   },
                   filename: function(req, file, callback) {
                       callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
                       console.log(req.files['imgUploader'][0].path); //Or use a loop for all files
                   }
               });

   var upload = multer({
                   storage: Storage
               }).array("imgUploader", 3);


   router.post('/uploadFile', upload, function(req,res,next){
       if(req.method == "POST"){
           [...]
       }
   });
   ```